# PHP documents stop working after adding CSS

Tags: php, html, css, authentication

I have been working on securing some pages on my server. I was able to create a log in screen and all, and it was working perfectly. After that, I decided to pretty it up by adding some CSS (background, horizontal center aligning, etc.). Right after that, for some reason, even after I put in my login info, nothing is getting processed while before, I would be able to see the rest of the page after login.

The way I am implementing my login is, I created a page called `login.php`, and I also have `index.php`, the page I am trying to access. In `index.php`, I used `require` to always access `login.php` first. I also have `theme.css` to make things look better.

What I do not understand is, how come it works before but now all of the sudden it stopped working. I did not even touch anything besides the CSS file after the login page was working.

Here are my codes:

index.php

```
<?php
    require('login.php');
?>

<?php
    require('session.php');
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Protected Page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST">
            Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            E-mail: <input type="text" name = "email"><br>
            Phone: <input type="text" name = "phone"><br>
            Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check Status"></form></td>
                <td><form action="logout.php" method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout"></form></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

login.php

```
<?php
    ## put sha1() encrypted password here - example is 'hello'
    $password1 = '43b1c8633e86765546bb1f44c4d654ed223fa064';
    ## username dictionary
    $uname1 = 'ismail';

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']))
    {
        $_SESSION['logged'] = false;
    }

    if (isset($_POST['password']))
    {
        if ((sha1($_POST['password']) == $password1) && ($_POST['username'] == $uname1))
        {
            $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
            $user = $_POST['username'];
            $pwd = $_POST['password'];
        }
        else
        {
            die ('Incorrect password');
            session_destroy();
        }
    }

    if (!$_SESSION['logged']):
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="vcenter">
        <div id="box-login">
            <img src="images/logo1.jpg" alt="PT BPI Logo" height="120px" class="center">
            <br />
            <table class="center">
                <form method="post">
                <tr>
                    <td>Username:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password:</td>
                    <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
                </tr>
                </form>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>

<?php
    exit();
    endif;
?>
```

theme.css

```css
/* 
    AUTHOR: Ismail Fadillah Adiputra
    VERSION: 1.0 | 20131030 
*/

/* general */
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#EDEDED, #9AC1DB); /* Safari */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(#EDEDED, #9AC1DB); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(#EDEDED, #9AC1DB); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: radial-gradient(#EDEDED, #9AC1DB); /* Standard syntax */
    }
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { font-family:'Tahoma', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#656464; text-transform:uppercase; font-weight:normal; text-align:center; }
h1 { font-size:3em; margin:0; } 
h2 { font-size:3.4em; }
p { font-family:'Tahoma', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#656464; font-size:13px; }
a { border-bottom:1px dotted; }
a:hover { border-bottom:1px solid; }
input { font-family:'Tahoma', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#656464; font-size:13px; }
td { font-family:'Tahoma', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color:#656464; font-size:13px; }

/* Appearance of the box in the login page */
#box-login {
    background:white;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 0px; /* padding top, right, bottom, left (in order) */
    border-radius:5px; /* rounded corner */
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888888; /* shadow */
    margin:185px auto; /* horizontal align center */
    width:275px;
    }

.container {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
}

.right {
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#b0e0e6;
}

/*
.center {
    margin:auto;
    width:50%;
}
*/

.center {
    /* center align the right way */
    float:none;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}

/* Changing the appearance of the input button */
input[type="submit"] {
    float:none;
    display:block;
    margin:10px auto;
    background:#EDEDED;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:'Tahoma';
    font-size:11px;
    color:#656464;
}
input[type="submit"]:hover {
    float:none;
    display:block;
    margin:10px auto;
    background:#656464;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:'Tahoma';
    font-size:11px;
    color:#EDEDED;
}
```

Any insight into this problem that you can provide me with, I would greatly appreciate it. Please let me know, and thank you!

Comment: There's no way that adding CSS can change the behavior of the script. It's just plain text as far as PHP is concerned.

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing is getting processed'? What's the content of add.php and session.php? Are you just talking about the login.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lots of mistake in your code and pages.
 I solved all the problems and make the pages as you want with integration of your code.

Change the pages according to the code given below(do not change your css and it's name.Your "CSS" is working perfectly.):

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="vcenter">
    <div id="box-login">
        <img src="images/logo1.jpg" alt="PT BPI Logo" height="120px" class="center">
        <br/>
        <table class="center">
            <form action="aunthiticate.php" method="post">
            <tr>
                <td>Username:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
            </form>
        </table>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

**Login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>Protected Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
```

**aunthiticate.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
## put sha1() encrypted password here - example is 'hello'
$password1 = '43b1c8633e86765546bb1f44c4d654ed223fa064';
## username dictionary
$uname1 = 'ismail';

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['logged']))
{
    $_SESSION['logged'] = false;
}

if (isset($_POST['password']))
{
    if (($_POST['password'] == $password1) && ($_POST['username'] == $uname1))
    {
        $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
        $user = $_POST['username'];
        $pwd = $_POST['password'];
        header('location:login.php');
    }
    else
    {
        die ('Incorrect password');
        session_destroy();
    }
}
 ?>
</body>
</html>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add.php" method="POST">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        E-mail: <input type="text" name = "email"><br>
        Phone: <input type="text" name = "phone"><br>
        Photo: <input type="file" name="photo"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    </form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Check Status"></form></td>
            <td><form action="logout.php" method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Logout"></form></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In login.php your `</form>` tag is in the wrong place.

The login.php form should be coded as follows:-

```
    <br />
    <form method="post">      <!-- moved! -->
    <table class="center">
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
    </form>                 <!-- moved! -->
```